# Values in a dataframe are between values in a second dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I try to check if dataframe values are between values in two columns of another dataframe.

First dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'num': [111, 222, 333],
    'desc': ['some_desc', 'some_desc', 'some_desc'],
})

     num    desc
0    111    some_desc
1    222    some_desc
2    333    some_desc
```

The second dataframe consists of ranges:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'n_start': [100, 300],
    'n_end': [199, 399]
})

     n_start n_end
0    100     199
1    300     399
```

For each value in df1 I need to check if it belongs to at least one range. It needs to be a new column with boolean value that reflects existing in ranges.
The result should be:

```
     num    desc         in_range
0    111    some_desc    1
1    222    some_desc    0
2    333    some_desc    1
```

There is a quite simple way to do it with using **iterrrows**:

```
def is_in_range(row):
    for _, num_range in df2.iterrows():
        if (row['num'] >= num_range['n_start']) & (row['num'] <= num_range['n_end']):
            return 1
        
    return 0

df1['in_range'] = df1.apply(is_in_range, axis=1)
```

But I would be very grateful for a pandas-way solution.

I've tried to compare directly:

```
df1['in_range'] = (df1['num'] >= df2['n_start']) & (df1['num'] <= df2['n_end'])
```

but it raises the error and I can't seem to find how to rewrite this.

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy `broadcasting`, (i.e. `[:, None]`) to check if if falls between `any` of the ranges. Very similar to your direct attempt.

```
import numpy as np

arr = df1.num.to_numpy()    # Values
lb = df2.n_start.to_numpy() # Lower Bound
ub = df2.n_end.to_numpy()   # Upper Bound

df1['in_range'] = np.any((arr >= lb[:, None]) & (arr <= ub[:, None]), axis=0).astype(int)

   num       desc  in_range
0  111  some_desc         1
1  222  some_desc         0
2  333  some_desc         1
```

Comment: This solution is very helpful. Thanks a lot!